# How do I check if ticket number is formatted using a function?

Tags: vb.net

I would like my function to follow some convention to check if my ticket number needs formatting or not.

If the convention is not met, then I would like to make some changes to the ticket number.

Ticket number **19K3072216** needs to be formatted to this **19-K3-07-002216** because it does not meet the following conditions.
My function should do the following.

1. Check if the 1st 2 digits has a value 0 - 9 (numeric)
2. Check if the 3rd digit has a value of A to Z
3. Check if the 4th digit has a value 0 - 9 (numeric)
4. Check if the 5th and 6th digits has a date value (e.g.2 digit year - 17, 90, 15 etc)
5. Check if the next 6 digits i.e. 7th - 12th digits are numeric.

Because ticket number **19K3072216** does not meet the above conditions, I would like my function to format it to look like this **19-K3-07-002216**

The string **strTicketNumber** should return formatted ticket number **19-K3-07-002216**

**My vb.net function**

```
Public Class Ticket_Code

    Public Shared Sub main()
        Dim strTicketNumber As String = FixTicketNumber("19K3072216")

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function FixCaseNumber(ByVal astrCaseNumber As String) As String
        Dim strCaseNumber As String = Replace(astrCaseNumber, "-", "")

        'Determine if ticket number is formatted
         How do I do this?


        'If ticket number is formatted add 2 zeros
         'How do I do this?

        'Else return unchanged
         'If ticket number is already formatted, just returned the number (original number)

        Return strCaseNumber

    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: You should be able to use regex to check if it already matches, otherwise it will be a pretty manual process of splitting the input, validating each rule, then concatenating the final string.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how I can use regex?

Comment: Are your year values just anything between 00-99 or are you limiting between say the last 30 years?

Comment: As mentioned it will depend on some more specifics around the year, but this is a simple one that will match your example `19-K3-07-002216`: `/^\d{2}-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}-\d{6}$` You can use the `Regex.Match()` to see if the input passes. I am not a regex expert so it could probably be better but this one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will really depend on your input and how different from the example it can be.
For instance will invalid input always be in the same format `19K3072216`or is there the chance it will be all digits, all letters, less/more than 10 characters long etc. All of these rules need to be considered and handled as necessary.

If the input will be from a user, never trust it and always assume it is the furthest from valid as possible. If the app can handle that case it can handle everything else

Something like this should get you started:

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim strTicketNumber As String = FixTicketNumber("19-K3-07-002216") ' or 19K3072216
        Console.WriteLine(strTicketNumber)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub


    Private Function FixTicketNumber(p1 As String) As String
        Dim fixed As String = ''
        Dim valid As Boolean = checkTicketNumber(p1)

        If valid Then
            Return p1 ' Ticket number is valid, no transformation needed
        Else
            'Assume invalid input will always be 10 characters (e.g. 19K3072216)
            'Split the input and Step through each rule one at a time
            'returning the necessary result/format string as you go

            '#1 Check if the 1st 2 digits has a value 0 - 9 (numeric)
            Dim ruleOne As String = p1.Substring(0, 2)
            'perform isNumeric, concatenate to fixed if everything is ok
            'fixed += ruleOne+"-"

            '#2 Check if the 3rd digit has a value of A to Z
            Dim ruleTwo As String = p1.Substring(3, 1)
            'check if its a letter, concatenate to fixed if everything is ok

            '... same for all the rules

        End If

    End Function

    Private Function checkTicketNumber(p1 As String) As Boolean
        'See if the input matches the rules
        'Check if the 1st 2 digits has a value 0 - 9 (numeric)
        'Check if the 3rd digit has a value of A to Z
        'Check if the 4th digit has a value 0 - 9 (numeric)
        'Check if the 5th and 6th digits has a date value (e.g.2 digit year - 17, 90, 15 etc)
        'Check if the next 6 digits i.e. 7th - 12th digits are numeric.
        Dim pattern As String = "\d{2}-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}-\d{6}"
        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(p1, pattern)

        Return match.Success

    End Function
```

It is hard to produce a fully working solution as there are too many unknowns about the input as an outsider.

Comment: Jake thanks for helping here. The valid input is 19-K3-07-002216 but you seem to think the other input is valid. So this is what I need to check to make sure other input matches or are converted to this format. How do I do that? What I want to do is format the 19K3072216 to look like 19-K3-07-002216 or 19K307002216. Either is fine for now

Comment: I modified your solution and now I am getting what I wanted. Thanks for helping